# Jquery draggable issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Basically what I want is that while dragging, if I go outside the containment area and release the mouse click there, the draggable element just sticks to the border from where I left the containement area. And when I move my cursor back in, the element sticks back to the cursor. It doesnt looks nice when you are just moving your cursor(not dragging) and the element is still getting dragged.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JdbaS/) is a fiddle to play with. Just drag and release the cursor outside the output area, you will get what I am talking about.

I was thinking of two ways

1. Restrict mouse movement to the containmenet area while being dragged(I searched for it and didnt find how to do it. Mayb thats not possible ?)
2. Revert the draggable to its position if the cursor leaves the containement area. (Still couldnt find a way to do this)

Any way or more bright ideas to achieve this ???

`Relevant Code` (for stackoverflow)

Comment: Working fine in here. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Works in Firefox, doesn't work in chrome

Comment: Is your real life (not fiddle) code also in an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a workaround for this. Works In IE8 and Chrome.

Added this code for the draggable element.

```
drag: function(){
     $('body').mouseleave(function(){
          $('body').mouseup();
     });
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdbaS/1/)

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Rembunator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004315/rembunator) for pointing out the flaw, I decided to use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for better performance, and shift the code from drag to start

```
start: function(){
     $('body').one("mouseleave", function(){
          $('body').mouseup();
     });
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Finally found a solution for it.

Here is the code:

```
var flag=true;
start: function( event, ui ){
    if(flag){
         flag = false;
         $('body').one("mouseleave", function(){
             $('body').mouseup();
              flag = true; //event occured, rebind
          });
     }
     else{
         flag = false;
     }
}
```

Thanks to [Rembunator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004315/rembunator) for his help

Comment: Although an excellent idea, I think this sets the mouseleave event everytime you drag.

Comment: Added a way to make the drag 'less nervous' with the help of a timer.

Comment: Ok, the reason why I wrote the function in drag becuse I did not wanted the event to get triggered every time when the user isnt dragging.
I think the number of time user may b moving the mouse in and out of that Iframe would be greater than he would drag an Element. What do you say ?

Comment: The event will only be fired when the mouse leaves the iframe. The drag event is likely to be fired a few hundred times per drag. To make things as clean as possible, you could add the mouseleave event to the body on drag.start and remove it on drag.stop.

Comment: I think adding and removing the event on every drag will take more processing time than firing a simple event.

Comment: The drag event fires on mousemove I think.

Comment: I think using .one() would not make that much of a difference regarding performance. Because just binding the event to the body will keep that firing without need

Comment: .one() will bind the event to the body once on the first drag which is also OK. It will from then on behave exactly the same as my example. The event will be caught every time the mouse leaves the iframe, which really isn't of any consequence at all. It's sometimes much more valuable to have readable code and not worry about tiny arbitrary performance issues. And still like I said: You could always consider unbinding the event on drag.stop.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because it's in an iframe.
It would be like dragging outside your browser. The mouseup event will not register in the page.

It looks like chrome doesn't allow that but firefox does.

Try this:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ESCu/4/)

```
$('body').mouseleave(function()
    {
    $(document).trigger("mouseup");
    });
```

It's your solution without setting the event everytime.

The overkill version (this will allow the user to temporarily (1 second) leave the iframe and return without losing the drag):

```
$('body').prop('mouseuptimer',null)
    .mouseleave(function()
        {
        var objTimer = setTimeout(function() 
            {
            $(document).trigger("mouseup")
            }, 1000);
        $(document).prop('mouseuptimer', objTimer);
        })
    .mouseenter(function()
        {
        var objTimer = $(document).prop('mouseuptimer');
        if (objTimer) clearTimeout(objTimer);
        });
$(function() 
    {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({revert: true });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid" });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

edit:

To answer your first question:

You can contain a draggable by adding 'containment' to the options i.e.:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: "document" });
```

But this can only contain the dragged element to the bounding box (in this case the "document", but it could also be i.e. "parent" or "#somediv").
The mouse cursor will still be able to move anywhere outside the iframe and dispatch events from there, beyond the scope of the iframe document.

Comment: So how can we enact the same behaviour in chrome ?

Comment: will look into that and let u know :)

Comment: Added an answer to your containment question.

Comment: Using containment body still doesnt dispatch events outside iframe in chrome