# Drag & Drop in iFrame using jQuery UI issue

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, drag-and-drop, draggable, iframe-app

I'm using jQuery UI. When I drag element in the iframe and I move mouse out of the iframe, the element is still in the draggable state. So when I move mouse back to the iframe, I can still drag it, like I would had left mouse button down.

How to avoid it? So that if I start to drag element, it stops when I go out of the iframe in the last draggable position?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a mouseup() when your pointer leaves the iframe so that the element being dragged is no released.

```
$('body').one("mouseleave", function(){
    $('body').mouseup();
});
```

There were more questions asked pertaining to my solution, so please refer my question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645510/jquery-draggable-issue) for more details