# How can I make jQuery UI "let go" of a draggable or sortable element when the mouse button is released over a sidebar or developer panel in Firefox?

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm working on a Web app allows users to reorder and delete items on the screen via the jQuery UI Sortable and Droppable widgets. Initially, I provided only one way to delete an item: drag it into an area with a trash icon and drop it. Now I'm adding the option to delete an item by dragging it off the edge of the screen and releasing the mouse button.

This new feature (delete by dragging offscreen) has been a little more complicated to set up than I expected, but I finally have most of the kinks worked out. One thing is still stumping me: In Firefox, there's a problem with the drag-and-drop functionality when other "panels" are present in the browser besides the main browser window -- for example, the bookmarks sidebar (which I usually keep docked to the left) and the developer tools (which I usually keep docked to the right or on bottom). If I pick up a sortable element, drag it behind one of these panels, and release the mouse button, jQuery UI continues to "hold on" to the element (i.e., keeps dragging).

**How to reproduce the problem:**

1. Go to the [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) page.
2. Press [control-B] to display Firefox's bookmarks sidebar.
3. Grab one of the sortable items, drag it over the bookmarks sidebar, and release the mouse button.
4. Move the mouse back to the box that the item came from. You'll see that the item is still sticking to the mouse as if being dragged, even though you're not holding down the mouse button any more.

**Desired behavior:** I want the Sortable widget to release the sortable item, just as it does when you move the pointer entirely outside the browser and release the mouse button.

Please note that this problem is particular to Firefox. (I'm running Firefox 51.0.1.) Google Chrome does not have the same problem. (When I dock the developer tools in Google Chrome to the bottom or to the right, I can release sortable items over the dev-tools area, and I get the desired behavior.) I haven't tested in IE, Safari, or other browsers yet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran into this problem a few years ago. I used to force release the cursor if it went outside of the body.

Here is the solution for the draggable:

```
var flag=true;
start: function( event, ui ){
    if(flag){
         flag = false;
         $('body').one("mouseleave", function(){
             $('body').one("mouseup", function(){
                 flag = true; //event occured, rebind
                 //do your stuff
              });
          });
     }
     else{
         flag = false;
     }
}
```

Here is the link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645510/jquery-draggable-issue)

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear in the way I phrased the desired behavior. I don't want a sortable item to be immediately deleted when the user drags it into the out-of-bounds area; I want it to be deleted only if the user drags it into the out-of-bounds area AND releases the mouse button. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DanRobinson  Oh. I have made some changes. I cannot test it at the moment, but I assume it should work fine. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Mandeep, I can't get your revised solution to work (even after changing both cases of "one" to "on" -- I assume that was a typo). It appears that the mouseup event simply won't register when the pointer is over one of Firefox's other "panels" (bookmarks or developer tools). Would you be willing to try adding your code to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lypodkyp)? My only concern with testing this way is that JSFiddle may introduce even more variables into the equation. (It uses iframes, for starters.)

Comment: @DanRobinson I used 'one' on purpose so as the event will not bind over multiple times. I will try to look into your fiddle later(cant promise though)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wasn't familiar with "one"! But I still can't get your code to work. I tried adding it to the Fiddle -- see [this forked version](https://jsfiddle.net/j7j4z3mm/). Maybe I didn't implement your code correctly? I would really appreciate it if you could make time to take a look.

Comment: The weird thing in the fiddle is, when i drag the item and release the mouse outside, the item vanishes when I move my cursor back in. Is it the same for you?

Comment: Yes, that's actually the intended functionality -- I want the user to be able to delete items by dragging them past the edge of the Web page. I've included a bunch of 'console.log' calls to help identify exactly what's happening and not happening.